# Unable to use \verb inside \cvitem

Tags: moderncv, verbatim

I'm trying to include some `\verb|text|` inside the body of a `cvitem`.

Compare:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=green]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Ducky}
\familyname{Duck}

\begin{document}
\section{\textsc{Technical Skills}}
    \cvitem{\textbullet}{\textbf{Programming languages:} Python, Java, R, bash, some comes here}
\end{document}
```

which compiles perfectly to:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=green]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Ducky}
\familyname{Duck}

\begin{document}
\section{\textsc{Technical Skills}}
    \cvitem{\textbullet}{\textbf{Programming languages:} Python, Java, R, bash, \verb|some| comes here}
\end{document}
```

which fails with the error: `! LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in argument.`.

I tried to look around in https://github.com/moderncv/moderncv, but found nothing. I didn't even manage to figure out where `cvitem` is defined. How can I use `\verb` inside the body of a `cvitem` item?

**Context:** I'm using [`mistletoe`](https://github.com/miyuchina/mistletoe) to render Markdown as LaTeX. This tool maps `` some `code` here `` to `some \verb|code| here`.

**Some more context (edit):** I'm using a custom function [`render_latex`](https://github.com/drorata/foo-cv/blob/ecec04b008c1ddda818558a8951d194cba9ba9eb/foo_cv/utils.py#L20) which yields a LaTeX snippet. This works as expected. The problem starts when I inject the LaTeX snippet into a template, and specifically into an argument of a LaTeX command.

**Using another delimiter:** If I replace `|` with `~`, then I can use `\verb` inside the `cvitem`:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,colorlinks,linkcolor=green]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}

\firstname{Ducky}
\familyname{Duck}

\begin{document}
\section{\textsc{Technical Skills}}
    \cvitem{\textbullet}{\textbf{Programming languages:} Python, Java, R, bash, \verb~some verb text~ comes here}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use verbatim material inside the argument of a command: this is entirely general

Comment: In the case of that context, maybe you can provide a MWE that uses the library itself and the source code before that? Otherwise the only advice we can possibly give is to not use the library or file a bug report with the author.

Comment: If the purpose of using `\verb` is to render its argument in the monospaced font, try replacing `\verb|some|` with `\texttt{some}`.

Comment: I tried to add more context. It is hard to construct a MWE here, but I hope that the additional info will help. I turns out that by replacing the delimiter, I can have `\verb` used inside the scope of the arguments of `\cvitem`. So, I'm still a little confused. @JosephWright? 

It seems like I have to focus on the way  `mistletoe` renders LaTeX from ``inline `code` in markdown``.

Comment: I sampled a few more delimiters (`:`, `/`, `!` and a few more) - with all of them I had the same problem. Using `~` somehow worked.

Comment: I don't understand the requirement, what part can you edit and what part you cannot? Why can you edit the delimiter character but cannot edit it to use `\texttt`?

Comment: Fair point. I experimented with the delimiter *manually*. Out of the box, `mistletoe` returns `\verb` with `|` as a delimiter. I am trying to find a way to include the output of `mistletoe` inside `\cvitem`. I think I have higher chances with tweaking the template where the output of `mistletoe` is injected. I'm trying to understand what are my options. This is why I am experimenting with the generated output manually.

Comment: Could you add the Markdown code to the question that produces the full 2nd MWE (the one with `\verb|code|`) when processed by mistletoe? This would make it easier to test some workarounds. I guess when LaTeX is the only target format (i.e., if you are not planning to render the Markdown directly or to convert to HTML using mistletoe) then it will be relatively easy to produce working LaTeX code.

Comment: I tried to add more details in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/drorata/b0b969e49f4bce91f67cf34efa6acf73). I guess this is a very specific case, that's hard to formulate as a MWE. I'm currently mostly interested in understanding why it does work with `~` as the delimiter...

Comment: `~` is an active character and expands to ` ` (space), so that `Q~Q~Q` produces `Q Q Q`. I expect the beginning of the answer to your question starts with: "If the users types `\verb !~! foo` then surprisingly we would get the space as the delimiter and thus “!~!foo” in the output. To avoid this scenario we check if `#1` has the character code of a space, if so we recurse otherwise we call `\@@sverb` (which is the original definition of `\@sverb`." (texdoc source2e, p626)

Comment: @Cicada but inside the `\cvitem` using ` ` (space) as the delimiter does *not* work and `~` does. I appreciate that my question here is not the best anymore. But I'm still trying to learn something out of it.

Comment: Expected behaviour: character #1 with character code of space is recursed over, otherwise the character is made active and becomes the \verb delimiter via lowercase code trick: `\catcode‘#1\active \lccode‘\~‘#1%`. `~` will not have a character code of space, so passes through the space-check step (this implies it is not expanded at that moment, presumably), it becomes its own lowercase character and is then called as such redefined as `\lowercase{\let~\verb@egroup}` ending the \verb grouping. So it only *appears* to be a delimiter, through its action as a delimiter definer.

Comment: Then there is this bit (same page): "If `\@sverb` is called from `\@verb` then space [meaning `\ ` ?] is already active and supposed to produce a real space. In this case we do nothing. Otherwise...". So I'm guessing `~` falls into the `Otherwise...` branch. Perhaps as a gap in logic, because of the recursive usage. Don't know if that would be a bug or a feature.

Comment: So, is the answer is: "In general it is impossible to use `\verb|foo|` inside a `\cvitem`. Actually it is not really possible inside other functions either. Still, it turns out that using `~` as a delimiter of `\verb` does work inside the `\verb`".  Is it the bottom line?